Office Word VBA Object "ListView1" on Windows 11
I have a problem with the controls in Word VBA. I am using the ListView1 object in my scripts, which works without any issues on Windows 10 and Office 2016. However, I can't get it to work on Windows 11.
Unfortunately, I could not find anything useful during my internet research. Does anyone know how I can re-embed the object or what alternative Microsoft offers for this on Windows 11?
Thanks for the help and best regards
Paul
I have tried both Office 365 (both x86 and 64Bit) and Office 2016. The controls on my Windows 10 machine come from the file C:\Windows\SysWow64\MSCOMCTL.OCX' and are included in VBA via 'Tools -> References' as 'Microsoft Windows Common Controls 6.0 (SP6). This file also contains other controls that work on Windows 11, but it seems that the ListView1 object does not work. I have successfully registered the OCX file via cmd as an administrator, but the Windows 11 PC still does not recognize the mentioned object.

-Verify MSCOMCTL.OCX is correctly registered.
-Ensure Office is fully updated.
-Use ListBox control as an alternative.
-Check for compatibility mode.
-Consider third-party ActiveX controls.
hope it'll work buddie
